# Android Studio 3 minSdk below 14

Tags: android, android-studio, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have an old phone running Android 2.3.6 (API 10). It was still supported in Android Studio 2.1.3, which I used for a long time, but in Android Studio 3, the lowest possible sdk is 14. The app I make is only for my personal use. So, is there a way to set minSdk to 10, or should I downgrade Android Studio? If so, which version still supported 2.3.6?

Comment: You have to update your SDK...from https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html

Comment: That's something with your SDK. I have installed all Android versions from 2.1 Eclair (API 7).

Comment: Well, I installed Gingerbread SDK, but when I try to create a new project, the lowest API shown is 14 (Android 4).

Comment: But I can normally compile older project from old Android Studio with minSdk 10.